# FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage works but Response.Redirect fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, cookies

I'm using a FormsAuthentication to manage login.I set cookie with some userdata that I need.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,  
                    txtUserName.Text,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                    false, 
                    roles, 
                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

HttpCookie authCookie =new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                    encryptedTicket);
authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
//doesn't work
//string url = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUserName.Text, false);
//Response.Redirect(url, false);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, false);
```

Using **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage** redirects correctly but it sets it's own cookie with an empty userdata overwriting mine, while **Response.Redirect** doesn't redirect at all.
Monitoring with fiddler I can see this:

```
//WITH Response.Redirect
POST to /WebApp/logon.aspx Result: 302
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4p0wrvbssiccgai0tspxo3zk
Set-Cookie: WWAuthCookie=SMALLCOOKIE; expires=Fri, 23-May-2014 08:20:58 GMT; path=/
Transport Location: /OST_VS/default.aspx

GET /WebApp/default.aspx HTTP/1.1 Result: 302
Transport Location: /WebApp/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebApp%2fdefault.aspx

GET /WebApp/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebApp%2fdefault.aspx HTTP/1.1
```

And this is with **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage**

```
POST /WebApp/Logon.aspx HTTP/1.1 Result: 302
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4p0wrvbssiccgai0tspxo3zk
Set-Cookie: WWAuthCookie=BIGCOOKIE; expires=Fri, 23-May-2014 08:27:33 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: WWAuthCookie=SMALLCOOKIE; path=/; HttpOnly

GET /WebApp/default.aspx HTTP/1.1 Result: 200
Transport Content-Encoding: gzip
```

The first thing you see is with FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage the cookie gets overwritten with a smaller cookie, and the second thing is that with Response, also the responses are different.Redirect it gets to default.apsx but gets back?
I really can't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was related to the **limit cap** that some browsers have on cookies.My userdata was **more than 4k** which caused it to fail to redirect since the browser apaprently rejected the cookie.Since FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage didn't have userdata it was smaller and could since redirect.

So what I did was compress my userdata string with Gzip to make it fit( it now sits at 2k).

Setting a separate cookie for userdata would work as well I suppose.